# Mysql query datagridview c#

Tags: c#, mysql, gridview, dataadapter

The query does not return value when I call it from ASP C# however when I connect the MySQL server and type the same query it returns right values. I couldn't discover the problem.

Here is the code segment:

```
try
{
    personquery = "select b.* from booking b, makes m  "+
                  "where m.personid="+ 
                  DataDeneme1.login.personid.ToString() +
                  "and m.bookingno=b.bookingno";
    con = new MySqlConnection(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Get("connectionString"));
    cmd.CommandText = personquery;
    con.Open();
    cmd.Connection = con;
    adap = new MySqlDataAdapter(personquery, con);
    adap.Fill(ds);
    // CheckBoxList1.DataSource = ds;
    // CheckBoxList1.DataBind();
    GridView1.DataSource = ds;
    GridView1.DataBind();
    con.Close();
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    Response.Write(ex.Message);
    Response.Write(ex.StackTrace);
}
```

The input and the output from mysql server:

```
mysql> select b.* from booking b, makes m  where m.personid=1 and m.bookingno=b.bookingno;
+-----------+-----------------+--------------+-------------+------------+-------------+  
| bookingno | reservationdate | dropoffplace | pickupplace | pickupdate | dropoffdate |  
+-----------+-----------------+--------------+-------------+------------+-------------+  
|         8 | 2011-05-09      | Ankara       | Ankara      | 2011-05-10 | 2011-05-15  |   
|         9 | 2011-05-09      | Ankara       | Ankara      | 2011-05-20 | 2011-05-25  |   
+-----------+-----------------+--------------+-------------+------------+-------------+  
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

and Exception message....

> You have an error in your SQL syntax;
>   check the manual that corresponds to
>   your MySQL server version for the
>   right syntax to use near
>   'm.bookingno=b.bookingno' at line 1 at
>   MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlStream.ReadPacket()
>   at
>   MySql.Data.MySqlClient.NativeDriver.GetResult(Int32&
>   affectedRow, Int32& insertedId) at
>   MySql.Data.MySqlClient.Driver.GetResult(Int32
>   statementId, Int32& affectedRows,
>   Int32& insertedId) at
>   MySql.Data.MySqlClient.Driver.NextResult(Int32
>   statementId) at
>   MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlDataReader.NextResult()
>   at
>   MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior
>   behavior) at
>   MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand.ExecuteDbDataReader(CommandBehavior
>   behavior) at
>   System.Data.Common.DbCommand.System.Data.IDbCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior
>   behavior) at
>   System.Data.Common.DbDataAdapter.FillInternal(DataSet
>   dataset, DataTable[] datatables, Int32
>   startRecord, Int32 maxRecords, String
>   srcTable, IDbCommand command,
>   CommandBehavior behavior) at
>   System.Data.Common.DbDataAdapter.Fill(DataSet
>   dataSet, Int32 startRecord, Int32
>   maxRecords, String srcTable,
>   IDbCommand command, CommandBehavior
>   behavior) at
>   System.Data.Common.DbDataAdapter.Fill(DataSet
>   dataSet) at
>   DataDeneme1.customerview.loadList() in
>   E:\VisualStudioProjects\DataDeneme1\DataDeneme1\customerview.aspx.cs:line
>   38

Comment: line 38 is --> adap.Fill(ds);

Comment: he is getting a SQL error, so the dataset fill is not going to even happen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would bet it has to do with the dynamic value `DataDeneme1.login.personid.ToString()`, since the exception states the next piece of text. Ensure your value is what you are expecting, a blank/whitespace value would cause this error.

**UPDATE**
Based on you comment I saw what I believe to be the issue. If the value is `1` then the result of this:

```
personquery = "select b.* from booking b, makes m  "+
              "where m.personid="+ 
              DataDeneme1.login.personid.ToString() +
              "and m.bookingno=b.bookingno";
```

Would be:

```
select b.* from booking b, makes m
where m.personid=1and m.bookingno=b.bookingno
```

No space, so add that to the initial query creation:

```
personquery = "select b.* from booking b, makes m  "+
              "where m.personid= "+ 
              DataDeneme1.login.personid.ToString() +
              " and m.bookingno=b.bookingno";
```

Which would result in:

```
select b.* from booking b, makes m
where m.personid= 1 and m.bookingno=b.bookingno
```

Comment: I debugged the code and saw the personid is "1". there is no problem with that

Answer (score 1):

Make sure there is a space in " and m.bookingno=b.bookingno". I mean before "and", like " and".